# momentjs - Create array of last 30 days

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I am using momentjs and am trying to create an array containing the last 30 days.

I think I can do this be creating a counter and then counting backwards, creating a moment for each day.

But is this the best method?  Does anybody know if momentjs has a function built in that can already do this?

Comment: what are you going to use the array for? if you are creating an array of dates - then you dont need to create a new instance of moment object per array item, you can have one instance of moment.js print out the date to your array. Otherwise no - your idea is a good way.

Answer (score 14):

As best I know, momentjs doesn't have any built in features for automatically creating an array containing moment instances, but you can easily construct an array of the previous thirty days using a short statement like this:

```
const lastThirtyDays = [...new Array(30)].map((i, idx) => moment().startOf("day").subtract(idx, "days"));
```

momentjs also has the ability to create objects that represent *durations* if that's of any help to you with your current problem.